# Backbone.js removing the model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been trying for hours now, without luck. If you could see on the image, I have mildly complex model. Image is taken from Chrome in debug.

I need to delete a model from collection, also **I need to be able to change** the URL where the backbone will shoot its ajax for delete. So in essence, this is my model structure:

```
attributes:
   favorites {
       bookmarkedArticles: [{id: 123123},{id: ...}],
       bookedmarkedSearches: [{}],
       dispatchesMailds: []
    }
```

How can I delete model in bookmarkedArticles with id of 123123?

I have tried this:

```
 var model = new metaModel(
              {
                  favourites: {
                      bookmarkedArticles: {
                          id: "123123"
                      }

                  }
              }
          );
model.destroy();
```

also this

```
aamodel.headerData.collection.remove(model);
```

No success at all.

[image: Model image from Chrome Debug]

Comment: _No success at all._ ... what does that exactly mean? Any error message? Which URL is called upon destroy? Please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information provided is not giving a lot of details, but I will try to answer considering two scenarios:

Option A:
You are trying to delete a model in the collection that has bookmarkedArticle.id="123123". if that is the case and considering the bookmarkedArticles it is just an Array of objects, I would suggest to filter the Collection using the underscore method [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and then delete the models returned by the filter.

```
var id = 123123;
var modelsToDelete = aamodel.headerData.collection.filter(function(model){
   // find in the bookmarked articles
   return _.find(model.get('bookmarkedArticles'), function(ba){
        return (ba.id === id);
   });
});
_.each(modelsToDelete, function(model){
  model.destroy();
});
```

Option 2: If you want to remove the bookmarked article '123123' associated to your main model using just the 'destroy' method, firstable you have to convert 'bookmarkedArticles' to a Backbone.Collection as it is just an Array of Objects, there are some utilities for Backbone that allows you to do this easily:

https://github.com/blittle/backbone-nested-models

But by default this is not possible, then, If you want to remove the 'bookmarkedArticle' you can create the Backbone.Model and then use the method destroy. Example:

```
var BookmarkedArticle = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){ 
   return '/bookmarkArticle/' + this.id;
  }
});

new BookmarkedArticle({"id": "123123","master": "5",...}).destroy();
```

Hope this information is useful and provide some guidance to solve your problem.